# Ruby on Rails CSS/JS error with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm building a web app on ROR5 and the layout/design is all done, with the CSS/JS files finalized. But when I open the app, click on one link, and navigate through the website, the CSS fails to load. More specifically, the CSS is all messed up. For example, say I go from 'Home' -> 'Page A', then if I backspace to 'Home' again (or click the logo to navigate to 'Home'), the 'Home' page will be messed up. Only when I **refresh** the page, I would get the correct display.

At first I thought it was a cache problem, but soon discovered that this line is causing the issue:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

When I delete this line, the display issue is no longer present. However, all JS effects/JS-based plugins would not work. I have a text editor, a few jQuery animations and tab navigations, which all don't work when I delete that line.
+ of course, instead of just deleting the line, I also tried to simply disable turbolinks by doing:
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
and removing turbolinks from my Gemfile. This also didn't work.

My **Gemfile** includes:
    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    gem 'jquery-rails'

And the remaining GEMs are all standard gems for my frontend side (bootstrap, SASS, font awesome etc).

My **application.js** looks like this:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

And for reference, my **application.html.erb** contains a  like the following:

```
<head>
    <title>..</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Adobe Typekit Scripts -->
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/ovy4zfg.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
</head>
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're loading in controller-specific stylesheets (`<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`). Turbolinks will append new stylesheets, but will not remove those that are absent in subsequent page loads. So here is the flow:

1. User visits Home
2. Stylesheet for Home's controller loaded
3. User visits Page A
4. Stylesheet for Page A's controller loaded *after* the Home CSS
5. Home CSS and Page A CSS will remain in the `head`

If possible, include all your CSS in the application.css manifest file. If you have some controller-specific styles, try adding a class to the body, e.g.:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %>">
```

Then you can scope your styles, e.g. for a `pages_controller`:

```
body.pages {
  …
}
```

Alternatively you could add `data-turbolinks-track="reload"` to your CSS link tag:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller], 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

However, this will mean that you will only get the benefits of Turbolinks when navigating between pages that use the same controller. When navigating between pages that use a different controller, you will get a full page load. This is because Turbolinks will track the presence or absence of the CSS and reload if it has changed.

One last thing: it is generally a good idea to add `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` to your application.css so that if you release a new version of your CSS, the users on the site will be up-to-date when the change goes live.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! I have many styles working, so I used the alternative method and adding data-turbolinks-track="reload" to my CSS link tag did the job perfectly! :)

Answer (score 3):

For people who came here with a *slightly* different problem:

When using different CSS files for different areas of your application (e.g. `application.css` for your regular app and `admin.css` for your admin area), Turbolinks fails to handle them properly when they do not live on separate (sub)domains.

So when `/admin` uses a different CSS file than the rest of the application, clicking a link to, say, `/admin/posts` and then using the back button to navigate back to `/`, the wrong CSS file will be used.

In this case, you need to set a root location for Turbolinks.

From the [docs](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#setting-a-root-location):

> By default, Turbolinks only loads URLs with the same origin — i.e. the same protocol, domain name, and port — as the current document. A visit to any other URL falls back to a full page load.
>
> In some cases, you may want to further scope Turbolinks to a path on the same origin. For example, if your Turbolinks application lives at `/app`, and the non-Turbolinks help site lives at `/help`, links from the app to the help site shouldn’t use Turbolinks.
>
> Include a `<meta name="turbolinks-root">` element in your pages’ `<head>` to scope Turbolinks to a particular root location. Turbolinks will only load same-origin URLs that are prefixed with this path.

To make the admin area under `/admin` from my example display the CSS correctly, include `<meta name="turbolinks-root" content="/admin">` in the layout's `<head>`.

Comment: Thank You!!!! I've been having an asset loading issue between admin and our normal user pages and was struggling with solutions until I stumbled upon your answer. Navigating between layouts works like a charm if you include turbolinks-root meta tags in your heads.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the same thing, reinstall Webpacker  and still for the error

Webpacker can't find application in C:/Users/Admin/friends/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:

1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
   Your manifest contains:
   {
   }